# Waiting for networking C# console application to fully start

Tags: c#, .net, performance, network-programming, udp

I have run into an issue with the slow C# start-up time causing UDP packets to drop initially. Below, I is what I have done to mitigate this start-up delay. I essentially wait an additional 10ms between the first two packet transmissions. This fixes the initial drops at least on my machine. My concern is that a slower machine may need a longer delay than this.

```
private void FlushPacketsToNetwork()
{
    MemoryStream packetStream = new MemoryStream();

    while (packetQ.Count != 0)
    {
        byte[] packetBytes = packetQ.Dequeue().ToArray();
        packetStream.Write(packetBytes, 0, packetBytes.Length);
    }

    byte[] txArray = packetStream.ToArray();
    udpSocket.Send(txArray);

    txCount++;

    ExecuteStartupDelay();
}

// socket takes too long to transmit unless I give it some time to "warm up"
private void ExecuteStartupDelay()
{
    if (txCount < 3)
    {
        timer.SpinWait(10e-3);
    }
}
```

So, I am wondering is there a better approach to let C# fully load all of its dependencies? I really don't mind if it takes several seconds to completely load; I just do not want to do any high bandwidth transmissions until C# is ready for full speed.

### Additional relevant details

This is a console application, the network transmission is run from a separate thread, and the main thread just waits for a key press to terminate the network transmitter.

In the `Program.Main` method I have tried to get the most performance from my application by using the highest priorities reasonable:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;
    ...
    Thread workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(worker.Run));
    workerThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
    workerThread.Start();
    ...
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop the stream...");
    WaitForKeyPress();

    worker.RequestStop = true;
    workerThread.Join();
```

Also, the socket settings I am currently using are shown below:

```
udpSocket = new Socket(targetEndPoint.Address.AddressFamily,
                       SocketType.Dgram,
                       ProtocolType.Udp);
udpSocket.Ttl = ttl;
udpSocket.SendBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
udpSocket.Blocking = true;

udpSocket.Connect(targetEndPoint);
```

The default `SendBufferSize` is 8192, so I went ahead and moved it up to a megabyte, but this setting did not seem to have any affect on the dropped packets at the beginning.

Comment: C# application? What is it? It does not give any specific idea about your application. Is your app Windows Forms, WPF or console based? Why don't you catch some events like Forms.Load or whatever fires when it is fully loaded.

Comment: @Mert Sorry about that. It is a multi-threaded console application. I updated my question to include that additional detail.

Comment: In my experience, "C# is ready for full speed" as soon as I start up. I've never experienced the packet drop problems you describe. Are you saying that the bytes aren't sent? Or is the problem with a client that's not receiving the packets?

Comment: @JimMischel The way I have been detecting packet drops is via Wireshark. My application thinks it has transmitted the correct number of packets, which I am tracking with the `txCount` member variable. However, at the very beginning of the stream Wireshark fails to capture the first 2-3 packets that are sent (I verfied this by doing a binary diff on the captured UDP stream with the file transmitted).

Comment: It is *required* that you don't care about losing packets when you use UDP.  If you can't afford that then you'll need to use TCP.  This is not just a startup issue, you can also lose them if the machine goes south for a while due to heavy loads.

Comment: @HansPassant I definitely agree that TCP is required for lossless transmission; however, in my applciation (MPEG2 transport streams via UDP) this isn't an option due to TCP's heavy bandwidth overhead. Unfortunately, I am experiencing packet loss in a virtually ideal setting (i.e., capturing outbound packets from the transmit machine, running at highest priority on it's own processor (1 of 8)) with little to no other network traffic. The fact that the startup delay works tells me this isn't really a network stack issue.

Comment: It's curious that you don't get an exception of any kind when this fails. Another thing to note is that the maximum size of a UDP datagram is something less than 64 kilobytes. I don't know if the `Socket.Send` method takes that into account and splits the packets. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @JimMischel I did take a look at this, but my transport stream packets are 188 bytes (as per the MPEG standard), and I only am queuing 5 (my target decoder can only buffer 5 at a time) of them so these packets are quite small at 940 bytes; they should also fit into a standard Ethernet frame being less than the 1500 byte nominal MTU. I also thought it was curious I got no exceptions, but I wrapped it in a try/catch block just in case, and I also verified the sent bytes were equal to 940, which check out. Thanks for taking the time to look at it!

Answer (score 0):

From the comments I learned that TCP is not an option for you (because of inherent delays in transmission), also you do not want to loose packets due to other side being not fully loaded.

So you actually need to implement some features present in TCP (retransmission) but in more robust and lightweight fashion. I also assume that you are in control of the receiving side.

I propose that you send some predetermined number of packets. And then wait for confirmation. For instance, every packet can have an id that constantly grows. Every N packets, receiving application sends the number of last received packet to the sender. After receiving this number sender will know if it is necessary to repeat last N packets.

This approach should not hurt your bandwidth very much and you will get some sort of information about received data (although not guaranteed).

Otherwise it is best to switch to TCP. By the way did you try using TCP? How much your bandwidth hurts because of it?